# Kotlin Firestore get data after search

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, search, android-recyclerview

I can search firestore with mutable list of keywords via kotlin. But before of the search i can see all user details in recyclerview. But at the end when i search sucessfully a username then user comes the screen but i dont see user's details. In addition when i clcik on user it is possible see userdetails in userdetail acitivity without any problem. The main problem focused on after search procces. I need to fix it Thanks in advance))
[Here is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuSLF.jpg)   [Here is my Firebase Firestore document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0J5o.jpg)

It is my data class

```
data class publiks(


    val username: String = "",
    val fullname: String = "",
    var rating : Long = 0,
    val rank: String = "",
    val downloadUrl : String = "",
    val userID : String = ""





) : Serializable
```

It is my some Activity codes

```
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var prUsers: RecyclerView
    private var searchList: List<publiks> = ArrayList()
    private var database: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    var posts_list = ArrayList<publiks>()
    private var recyclerViewAdapter = new_adapter(posts_list, this)
    private lateinit var swtest: EditText
```

////

```
override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                get_information()


                val searchText: String = swtest.text.toString()

                searchData4(searchText.toLowerCase())

            }

        })


    }

    private fun searchData4(searchText: String) {


database.collection("ProfPic").whereArrayContains("lowercase_username", searchText).
      get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                searchList = task.result!!.toObjects(publiks::class.java)
                recyclerViewAdapter.post_list = searchList
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

//////

```
private fun get_information() {
        database.collection("ProfPic",).orderBy(
            "Username",
            Query.Direction.DESCENDING
        ).addSnapshotListener { snaphot, exception ->
            if (exception != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, exception.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                if (snaphot != null) {
                    if (!snaphot.isEmpty) {
                        val documents = snaphot.documents
                        posts_list.clear()
                        for (document in documents) {
                            val usernamelady = document.get("Username") as String
                            val fullnamelady = document.get("Fullname") as String
                            val ranklady = document.get("Rank") as String
                            val ratinglady = document.get("Rating") as Long
                            val downloadUrl = document.get("downloadUs") as String
                            var userID = document.get("userID") as String



                            val download_post = publiks(  usernamelady,  fullnamelady,  ratinglady, ranklady, downloadUrl,  userID
                            )
                            posts_list.add(download_post)


                        }
                    }
                    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Yes Sir. Firstly thanks for response. My problem is when i search a user in search field i get the target user by arraycontained user. But i dont see user details after search in recyclerveiw. I see only my recyclerrow but i dont see there user details in recyclerrow. Before i search a user it shows everything very well. But after search i can find target user but, that users details does not show, which i added photo in my question. So i need get user details to show after search. I Think i am missing something else